# Resize Height of Object/Embed with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an object/embed on my page:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="{$height}" id="chat_shell"
        data="js/8wayrun/irc/lightIRC.swf?host={$server}{$params}{$extras}{$styles}">
    <param name="movie" value="js/8wayrun/irc/lightIRC.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="host={$server}{$params}{$extras}{$styles}" />
</object>
```

When I click a button, it activates some jQuery scripting...

```
$('#chat_shell').animate({ height: $('#chat_shell').height() + slideHeight }, slideSpeed);
```

But instead, when I click the button, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? I know a possible solution is to wrap the object/embed into a DIV, set the height to 100% and then edit the height of the DIV; but that is an inelegant solution and often has compatibility problems as height should really never be set to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking that  `$('#chat_shell').height()` works on it's own?

I tried out your code on a flash element on my site and it worked fine, so it would lead me to believe the issue is arising from elsewhere.

Have you checked the event handler for your button fires properly?
Have you checked that JQuery is initializing properly?
Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: yes, $('#chat_shell').height() fires on it's own without any issues... it only seems to be an issue with the animated version.

Comment: that's an odd one, you could always try setting the height to a static value and see if it occurs

Comment: yep, set the height to static and still happened.

Comment: try setting it via css: `$('#chat_shell').css({height: specificHeight});`

Comment: If you want to see this in action... goto: http://www.8wayrun.com/chat/ and click the "show stream" button.

Comment: Had a quick play and I get that error for every property I try and animate on that element. Could be a jquery bug. Have you tried any other versions, or uncompressed versions?

Comment: Tried different versions of jQuery... same issue.

Comment: I'd try something like this then:

`function resize(dHeight, duration){
 var diff = dHeight / (duration / 50); // Work out how far we want to move every 50ms
 var curr = 0;
 var elem = $("#chat_sell");
 var initH = elem.height();
 var intF = setInterval(function(){
  curr += diff;
  elem.height(initH + curr);
  if(curr >= dHeight){
   clearInterval(intF);
  }
 },50);
}

resize(slideHeight, slideSpeed);`